# The logic behind subset in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a subset of a data.frame but I don't understand the logic behind the result. I'm used to work with SQL and I thought that I could isolated one value of the matrix to became easier to work.

```
// created a dataset example, with any values and then I combined
Country <- c('Argentina','Brazil','Chile')
Quantity <- c(1, seq(5)) 
M <- cbind(Country,Quantity)
M <- as.data.frame(M)

// the result 
  Country       Quantity
1 Argentina     1
2 Brazil        1
3 Chile         2
4 Argentina     3
5 Brazil        4
6 Chile         5

// now I tried to isolated
test <- M[M$Country=="Brazil",]   

// and still good
   Country    Quantity    
2  Brazil     1    
5  Brazil     4
```

When I used the command "table", that for me is the closed to count(*), the count result is OK, but it brings all the Countries and I don't understand this result, because I filtered only Brazil latter.

```
    table(test)

               Quantity
    Country    1 2 3 4 5
    Argentina  0 0 0 0 0
    Brazil     1 0 0 1 0
    Chile      0 0 0 0 0
```

Thanks,

Filipe

Comment: The output from `table(test)` looks sensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have factors. The levels are kept even after the subset. You can avoid the whole thing ahead of time with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
M <- data.frame(Country, Quantity, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test <- M[M$Country=="Brazil",]   
table(test)
#         Quantity
# Country  1 4
#   Brazil 1 1
```

If you need factors you can also use `droplevels` to remove the unnecessary levels:

```
test <- M[M$Country=="Brazil",]   
test2 <- droplevels(test)
table(test2)
#         Quantity
# Country  1 4
#   Brazil 1 1
```